# Are there better ways to have different actions chosen in a function based on its inputs?

Tags: python, performance, readability

I've made a generic function to generate a 2D grid of size x, y, `make_grid`.

```
def make_grid(x, y, mode="empty"):
    if mode == "rand":
        def filling():
            return randint(0, 1)
    else:
        def filling():
            return 0
    grid = []
    for r in range(x):
        row = []
        for c in range(y):
            row.append(filling())
        grid.append(row)
    return grid
```

I've set it up to define the `filling` function based on the input `mode` so that I don't end up running a bunch of `if`s being checked unnecessarily over the for loops - the hope is that over a large grid this would save considerable time.

I'm not sure, however, that this would be the most Pythonic way of achieving this - it doesn't feel clean to define functions within functions in this way. Can anyone suggest better (clearer or more efficient) methods? I feel like lambdas might be the right way, but I haven't ever really got comfortable with them... I should, at the least, be able to define functions elsewhere, choose which one should be called before the for loop, and then use it during the for loops, right?

Edit: here's a more minimal example, as I was shamefully lazy at first and didn't bother making a proper one... (I'm leaving the original so that answers still make sense.)

```
def example(mode=0):
    if mode == 1:
        def action_to_take():
            print("mode1")
    else:
        def action_to_take():
            print("mode_other")
    for r in range(1000):
        for c in range(1000):
            action_to_take()
```

Just imagine that the conditionally defined `action_to_take` function is complicated enough to warrant this question, and the loop goes round enough times to make questioning the performance of the code reasonable.

Comment: It's pretty uncommon to conditionally define functions like this. Why not use `row.append(x)` where x is just conditionally defined in a preceding line?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @duhaime Yes, I figured conditionally defining functions would be pretty abnormal. The issue with conditionally defining what I append in the preceding line would be that the conditional would be calculated x*y times, even though it has to come to the same conclusion every time

Comment: sorry @Peter, that was lazy of me. More minimal example added.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a dict:

```
def fill_rand():
    return randint(0, 1)

def default_fill():
    return 0

# you can add how  many modes you want
filling_mode = {
    'rand': fill_rand,

}

def make_grid(x, y, mode="empty"):
    filling = filling_mode.get(mode) or default_fill

    grid = []
    for r in range(x):
        row = []
        for c in range(y):
            row.append(filling())
        grid.append(row)
    return grid
```

Comment: Thanks, a dict is a nice clean way of dealing with this

Answer (score 1):

It's uncommon to conditionally define functions like this. You can simplify this and shorten it quite a bit with a more straightforward approach:

```
import numpy as np

def make_grid(x, y, mode='empty'):  
  if mode == 'rand':
    return np.random.randint(0, high=2, size=(y, x)).tolist()
  return np.zeros((y, x)).tolist()
```

If you don't like numpy, I'd use list comprehensions because it keeps the code concise:

```
from random import randint

def grid(x=1, y=1, zeros=False):
  return [[0 if zeros else randint(0,1) for _ in range(y)] for _ in range(x)]

a = grid(x=7, y=10, zeros=False)
```

It's tough to generalize too much beyond this though. In general, it's *quite* uncommon to conditionally define a function. It's much more common to conditionally define a value inside a function (see the x if b else y syntax in my `grid()` function above for an example).

If you post your actual situation, or more info about the functions you conditionally want to instantiate, we can probably give more info. Either way, if you need to support both behaviors, it usually makes sense to define those functions outside of a conditional but call them inside the conditional as @kederrac has done...

Comment: Thanks @duhaime, I didn't know numpy's randint had a size parameter. Useful to know and definitely avoids unnecessary for looped conditionals in the case of my example! Would be great to have an answer for the general type of problem though. If numpy didn't exist in this case, I'd be stuck having to write my own `numpy.random.randint` and `numpy.zeros`, which would involve a fair bit of duplication of effort between the two. Would I be right to say that this delegates the issue I'm trying to find the cleanest solution for to other functions?

Comment: @JRVeale I added a little to my answer to show that you could replicate the required behaviors of numpy pretty easily and concisely with list comprehensions. That style might be too terse for you, but as a codebase gets to be tens of thousands of lines it can be helpful to keep things as succinct as possible. In any event, there's no delegation so to speak in the second example, except to the `random` module I suppose...

Comment: Thanks again, I wasn't aware of list comprehensions, and they look like another great solution (assuming that I understand the way they run - in your example, calculating the conditional once, and then calling the resultant choice [`0` or `randint(0,1)`] in each iteration of the loops). In response to your edit suggesting I post my actual situation: I don't have a specific situation in mind, rather I was interested in better methods of avoiding repeatedly calculating conditionals within loops in general. I'd say you and @kederrac's answers have provided excellent answers to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the case where the mode argument is only being used to determine which action to take at a certain point within the function, another option I just thought of would be to simply pass the function name as a parameter. As below:

```
def action_one():
    print("mode1")


def action_default():
    print("other")


def example(func=lambda *args: None):
    for r in range(1000):
        for c in range(1000):
            func()
```

You could then call `example(action_default)` or `example(action_one)`, and with that lambda expression there as a default value even `example()` - which will do nothing at the point where `func` is called.